# На какой ивент привязана валидация в Ангуляре?

Tags: angular2, angular4, angular

На какой ивент привязана валидация input в Ангуляре?

Судя по всему, на события keyPress, keyUp, потому как если динамически изменять value инпута - валидатор ругается.

Comment: Другими словами если изменять значение формы из вне простым js - то слушатель формы ничего об этом не знает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Валидация не привязана ни на какое событие. Валидатор - это обычная функция, возвращающая `ValidationErrors | null`, или в случае с асинхронным валидатором `Promise<ValidationErrors | null> | Observable<ValidationErrors | null>`.

Когда вы используете директиву `formControlName` или `formControl` - под капотом инициализируется большое количество директив, такие как `NgControlStatus`, `FormControlDirective`, `FormControlName` и тд. К этим директивам привязаны статические метаданные, такие как `host`:

```
host: { '(change)': 'onChange($event.target.value)', '(blur)': 'onTouched()' }
```

На событие `change` вызывается функция `onChange`. `onChange` сеттит текущее значение контрола и по цепочке вызывает метод `updateValueAndValidity` снизу вверх (реактивные формы это дерево). `updateValueAndValidity` в свою очередь вызывает функцию `_runValidator` (проходится в цикле по массиву валидаторов и вызывает их, куда аргументом передает текущий контрол), результат `_runValidator` присваивается переменной `errors`. После этого вызывается функция `_updateStatus`, которая меняет статус контрола с `valid` на `invalid` и наоборот. После чего генерируется событие через `statusChanged: EventEmitter<void>` вверх по дереву о том, что данный контрол не прошел/прошел валидацию и его статус изменился, перерисуй-ка форму.

Как обновить значение извне:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('Артур', {
        validators: [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(4)
        ]
    })
});

public get name(): AbstractControl {
    return this.form.get('name') !;
}
```

В шаблоне можно использовать свойство `name`:

```
<button (click)="name.setValue(null)">Изменить имя</button>
```

Getter используется для избежания дублирования кода, чтобы каждый раз не писать `form.get('name') !.setValue(null)`. Изменив значение на `null` - контрол и сама форма станет невалидной:

```
console.log(this.form.invalid === true); // true
```

Точно также к свойству `name` можно обращаться в самом компоненте:

```
@Component({
    selector: ....,
    template: '<button (click)="changeNameValueToNull()">Изменить имя</button>'
})
export class .... {
    public form = ....

    public get name ....

    public changeNameValueToNull(): void {
        this.name.setValue(null);
    }
}
```

Чтобы изменять валидность извне Angular - директивы слушают события, нужно вручную вызвать диспатч события:

```
const input = document.querySelector('.some-input');
input.value = '1';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

А вообще избегайте такого, это неправильный подход.

Comment: @Jony, если это является ответом на ваш вопрос - пометьте галочкой, либо же напишите какие у вас еще есть вопросы - я дополню ответ

Comment: Обязательно - я еще не успел ознакомиться с вашим ответом.

Comment: Видимо Вы не поняли моей проблемы. У меня есть сторонний js скрипт - и отдельно компонет Angular. Из стороннего скрипта я изменяю value значение input поля, нативно: element.value = "value"; при этом Ангуляр не отслеживает в этом случае изменение значения поля и соответсвенно не запускает валидацию. Или же о иной логике - но суть в том, что если динамически иизменить значение поля (не средствами Ангуляр - реативные формы) - тогда поле остается всегда невалидным - даже если данные введены правильно.

Comment: @Jony, обновил ответ

Comment: Не понятно до конца. Вы имеете ввиду добавить класс ``` .some-input``` в форму ангуляр

Comment: А если не знаю класс а знаю просто `e`?

Comment: @Jony, ваш вопрос звучал `как изменять 'value' из стороннего скрипта и запускать валидацию`, вы получили ответ, я не знаю как вы именуете ваши элементы, это не относится к вопросу

Comment: @Jony, напишите пожалуйста что вам еще непонятно или не получается, я дополню ответ нужной информацией, лучше покажите мне тот участок кода где вы изменяете `value` вручную вне зоны видимости Angular

Comment: Поле изменяю этим куском кода: ``` if (this.VKI_target.setSelectionRange && !this.VKI_target.readOnly && !this.VKI_isIE) {
        var rng = [this.VKI_target.selectionStart, this.VKI_target.selectionEnd];
        this.VKI_target.value = this.VKI_target.value.substr(0, rng[0]) + text + this.VKI_target.value.substr(rng[1]);
        if (text == "\n" && this.VKI_isOpera) rng[0]++;
        this.VKI_target.setSelectionRange(rng[0] + text.length, rng[0] + text.length);

        console.log(this.VKI_target);

      }```

Comment: что-то страшное :-)) `this.VKI_target.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` попробуйте, если я правильно понял, что это инпут ваш

Comment: После этого куска года вызвать ваш?

Comment: Да - это мой активный инпут

Comment: вы должны вызвать это в том месте, где хотите уведомить Angular запустить валидацию, в каком-то из кусков, после сеттинга `this.VKI_target.value`

Comment: А где это лучше сделать в ngAfterViewChecked() {} ?

Comment: ну вы `value` сеттите в каком-то методе, верно?

Comment: я сет делаю из другого файла js - который просто включен в html - но не является частью самого angular проект

Comment: вам удобно связаться в телеграме?

Comment: Да, конечно - спасибо! https://t.me/oligarhe